# Convert tensorflow saved_model from float32 to float16

Tags: tensorflow, casting

I have a tensorflow saved model with `float32` weights in a directory structure like below,

```
large_model\
    variables\
        variables.data-00000-of-00001   (3.6GB)
        variables.index
    saved_model.pb
```

I would like to cast all weight to `float16` in order to reduce the size of the model. I have found `tf.cast()` method that can be applied to tensors. But it seems that there is no such method for casting the whole weights of a model. I guess that I have to read all layers of the model one by one and manually cast the weight to `float16` and then save it using `model.save()`, but I don't know how to do that.

**Note1:** I do NOT have access to the python code of the model definition, only the saved model.

**Note2:** I do NOT want to save it as `tflite` format.

Answer (score 1):

This is rather not a recommended method, I just tested it with a simple small model. You could load your model and then save it as a `.h5` file. Then you can to replace `float32` with `float16` in that file:

```
cat model.h5 | sed s/float32/float16/g > new_model.h5
```

So, I have a simple model, with `Lambda` layers which print out the `dtype` of the received tensor:

```
l = inputs
l = Lambda(lambda x: tf.print(f'dtype of tensor: {x.dtype}') and x)(l)
l = Conv2D(128, 7, activation='relu', padding='same')(l)
l = MaxPooling2D(2)(l)
l = Lambda(lambda x: tf.print(f'dtype of tensor: {x.dtype}') and x)(l)
...
```

During training it shows:

```
dtype of tensor: <dtype: 'float32'>
dtype of tensor: <dtype: 'float32'>
```

Then I save it, transform it with `sed`, and in a new file, without using the model definition, I load the model:

```
model = tf.keras.models.load_model('new_model.h5')
```

Now during training it shows:

```
dtype of tensor: <dtype: 'float16'>
dtype of tensor: <dtype: 'float16'>
```

When I check the layer `dtypes`, they are also shown as `float16`

```
for layer in model.layers:
    print(layer.name, layer.dtype)
input_1 float16
lambda float16
conv2d float16
max_pooling2d float16
lambda_1 float16
```

Comment: Please note that I do not have access to the python code of the model definition. When I run `model = tf.keras.models.load_model('new_model.h5')`, I get the error: `No model config found in the file at <tensorflow.python.platform.gfile.GFile object at 0x7f549dadb5b0>.`

Comment: It's not possible to save the model in `.h5` format and reload it? Make sure you save the whole model, not just the weights